# detect small image in large one

Tags: python, image-processing

[image]

I am new to Machine learning.
I have an image with size 28x200 as above. I have to detect images of size 28x28 in the large picture of size 28x200. For example, in this large image, there are three 28x28 images. How could I detect them? I read some answers using OpenCV but I could not manage to make it work with numpy array (.npy file), the answers are mainly concerned with JPG. Any solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It occurs to me that you detect the edges and see if it has 4 vertices and the aspect ratio matches the dimensions you want.

Comment: Could you run a convolution where the kernel is the image you're looking for? Peaks in the convolved image would correspond to where the sub-image shows up in the larger one

Comment: @JasmineN if all your images like that, you can use simple image processing techniques, start with **median filter** to eliminate **salt an pepper noise**, then run **edge detection** algorithm to find the borders of your images, and since you know the size of your small images `28x28` you can find the square external edges using **template matching**  or **Hough Line detection** techniques.